# Android google maps with 3D markers?

Tags: android, maps, markers

I'm a beginner in Android development.

Trying to make an app with 3D markers on a google maps, but obviously only able to do flat or regular markers.

is there a way to make 3D markers / models somehow?
Maybe an invisible layer of canvas above the map or another map service other than google?

Thanks!

Comment: any updates on this?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an article about that on Medium. You can check it out, it's a long explanation. But basically, you can use a layer above the map with sprite animations :p

https://lucasrodriguesgui.medium.com/rendering-and-animating-3d-markers-using-android-google-maps-sdk-3dfd0d597a2a

Comment: Please be careful about over-promoting your own blogs/repos as answers; I refer to [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66143407/10871073).

Comment: Great!

Now that this article is 2 years old. Do you know of any better implementation to achieve this?